# Read ini file locate at the src level in Android Project

Tags: android

I have an apiconfig.ini and inside the file I have

```
# THE MOVIE DB API KEY
api_key = API_KEY
```

I just want get API_KEY(value) and set on String.

I create a class to read the Ini file:

```
public class ReadIniFile {
    //--- Get Key or Value from a .ini File ---//
    private String configurationFilePath;
    private final String defaultConfigPath = "apiconfig.ini"; //Doesn't Work
    private HashMap<String, String> iniFile;

    public HashMap<String, String> getIniFile() {
        return iniFile;
    }

    public void setIniFile(HashMap<String, String> iniFile) {
        this.iniFile = iniFile;
}

public ReadIniFile(String iniConfFilePath, String... keys) {
    configurationFilePath = iniConfFilePath == null ? defaultConfigPath : iniConfFilePath;
    Ini ini = loadIni();
    if (ini != null) {
        if (keys.length > 0) {
            for (String key : keys) {
                iniFile.put(key, ini.get(key).toString());
            }
        }
    }
}

public ReadIniFile(String iniConfFilePath, String key) {
    configurationFilePath = iniConfFilePath == null ? defaultConfigPath : iniConfFilePath;
    Ini ini = loadIni();
    if (ini != null) {
        iniFile.put(key, ini.get(key).toString());
    }
}

public ReadIniFile(String... keys) {
    configurationFilePath = defaultConfigPath;
    Ini ini = loadIni();
    if (ini != null) {
        if (keys.length > 0) {
            for (String key : keys) {
                iniFile.put(key, ini.get(key).toString());
            }
        }
    }
}

public ReadIniFile(String key) {
    configurationFilePath = defaultConfigPath;
    Ini ini = loadIni();
    if (ini != null) {
        iniFile.put(key, ini.get(key).toString());
    }
}

public Ini loadIni() {
    try {
        File file = new File(configurationFilePath);
        Ini ini = new Ini(new File(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        return ini;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public HashMap<String, String> getAllIni() {
    return iniFile;
}

public String getSpecificValueIni(String key) {
    return iniFile.get(key);
}

public Collection<String> getAllValues() {
    return iniFile.values();
}

public String getSpecificKeyValueIniToString(String key) {
    return key + " = " + iniFile.get(key);
}
}
```

But when i run the code, they don't find the apiconfig.ini file

How can i get the path to the file? remember the file are locate at src directory level, like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1Axx.png)

Or there is any better way to save an API key outside hardcode?

Comment: what is path of `apiconfig` file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the API key as a string resource. It would go in the `strings.xml` file.

```html
<string name="api_key">API_KEY</string>
```

From there you can use it like any other string resource in Android.

Comment: The problem is that I'm using github, so I don't want to send this file all the time, but i've created a new file config_string.xml put api_key there like a string tag, and get in my view. So, it works! Thanks